# pylint E4010: Unable to import 'google.appengine.ext'

Tags: visual-studio-code

I have these import in my flask app.

```
from google.appengine.ext import deferred
from google.appengine.api.taskqueue import TaskRetryOptions
from google.appengine.ext import ndb
```

I got errors:
[image]
on settings.json it says:

```
// List of paths to libraries and the like that need to be imported by auto complete engine. E.g. when using Google App SDK, the paths are not in system path, hence need to be added into this list.
  "python.autoComplete.extraPaths": []
```

so I tried:

```
{
    "python.autoComplete.extraPaths": ["/Users/macbookpro/Developer/google-cloud-sdk/platform/google_appengine/google/appengine.ext"]
}
```

But it does not solve the problem.
How to fix the pylint error?
I am on Mac OS High Sierra, Visual Studio Code.

Answer (score 0):

Try to Remove **/google/appengine.ext** from the path. Restart VSCode.